# Trigger: Help understanding why following trigger statements wont work?

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to learn apex. Need help understanding why the following statements wont work

**c.Account = at.Account__c**
OR 
**c.AccountId = at.Account__cId (linking the Id's)**

This works: **c.AccountId = at.Account__c** (Want to understand why)

'c' is object of contact object; 'at' is object of custom attendee object). The goal of the statement is to pull account information from the attendee object into the new contacts.

Code:

Refrence code which uses the above statements:

```
trigger CreateContact on Attendee__c (after insert, after update) {

List <Contact> contactToInsert = new List <Contact>();
for(Attendee__c at :Trigger.new){

Contact c = new Contact();

c.Division__c = at.Division__c;

c.FirstName = at.First_Name__c;
c.LastName = at.Last_Name__c;
c.AccountId = at.Account__c;

contactToInsert.add(c);

}

insert contactToInsert;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two properties in an SObject for each "lookup" field. For standard fields, they are named such as `Account` and `AccountId`. The first is an SObject that represents related information (e.g. record.Account.Name would be a contact's account's name). The second field is the literal ID value that you would expect to see in the field.

The SObject reference only exists in Apex Code/SOQL. For custom fields, they are named `Field__r` and `Field__c`, where `Field__r` is an SObject that represents the lookup data, and `Field__c` represents the literal ID value you'd expect to see in the field.

Normally, you'd assign the SObject reference when using `upsert`, which lets you associate the record based on the value passed into the SObject reference. In the more usual case, you'd assign the ID value to the record lookup field, if known.

So, for your first attempt, you were trying to assign an ID to an SObject reference, and in the second attempt, `__cId` wouldn't reference an actual value. Only standard fields gain the "ID" modifier to represent the field (or, conversely, lose the "ID" to represent a reference to another object).

Comment: thx sfdcfox. That helps!